# SQL Many-to-One pivot

Tags: mysql

Given a data structure like so:

```
CREATE TABLE records (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE records_data (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  record_id INT NOT NULL,
  record_data_type_id INT NOT NULL,
  data VARCHAR(255),
  UNIQUE(record_id, record_data_type_id)
);

CREATE TABLE records_data_types (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);
```

And (sample) data like so:

```
INSERT INTO records_data_types (name) VALUES ('Location');
INSERT INTO records_data_types (name) VALUES ('Ice Cream Flavor');
INSERT INTO records_data_types (name) VALUES ('Slogan');
INSERT INTO records_data_types (name) VALUES ('Starting Pay');
INSERT INTO records_data_types (name) VALUES ('Grand Opening Date');

INSERT INTO records (name) VALUES ('Business A');
INSERT INTO records (name) VALUES ('Business B');
INSERT INTO records (name) VALUES ('Business C');
INSERT INTO records (name) VALUES ('Business D');

INSERT INTO records_data (record_id, record_data_type_id, data) VALUES (1, 1, 'New York, NY');
INSERT INTO records_data (record_id, record_data_type_id, data) VALUES (1, 2, 'Chocolate');
INSERT INTO records_data (record_id, record_data_type_id, data) VALUES (1, 3, 'The only apple!');
INSERT INTO records_data (record_id, record_data_type_id, data) VALUES (1, 4, '27');
INSERT INTO records_data (record_id, record_data_type_id, data) VALUES (1, 5, '2017-09-01');
INSERT INTO records_data (record_id, record_data_type_id, data) VALUES (2, 1, 'Chicago, IL');
INSERT INTO records_data (record_id, record_data_type_id, data) VALUES (2, 2, 'Vanilla');
INSERT INTO records_data (record_id, record_data_type_id, data) VALUES (2, 3, 'Windy and tasty');
INSERT INTO records_data (record_id, record_data_type_id, data) VALUES (2, 4, '10');
INSERT INTO records_data (record_id, record_data_type_id, data) VALUES (2, 5, '2017-01-01');
INSERT INTO records_data (record_id, record_data_type_id, data) VALUES (3, 1, 'Seattle, WA');
INSERT INTO records_data (record_id, record_data_type_id, data) VALUES (3, 2, 'Rocky Road');
INSERT INTO records_data (record_id, record_data_type_id, data) VALUES (3, 5, '2011-05-14');
INSERT INTO records_data (record_id, record_data_type_id, data) VALUES (4, 2, 'Mint Chip');
INSERT INTO records_data (record_id, record_data_type_id, data) VALUES (4, 3, 'Toothpaste and orange juice');
```

[(Here's a db-fiddle)](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/keyzUfoYsXU9yFzyEEyu7Q/4)

I'm looking to get a pivoted result set where the column headers are `records_data_types.name` with each row belonging to a `record` entry.

For each entry, I'm looking to get:

```
SELECT 
  records.name as RecordName,
  records_data_types.name as DataType,
  records_data.data as Data
FROM records_data
  INNER JOIN records 
    ON records_data.record_id = records.id
  INNER JOIN records_data_types 
    ON records_data_types.id=records_data.record_data_type_id
WHERE records.id = ? -- for each record, pivoted;
```

This data is being handled by code (PHP in this case, but it doesn't really matter what language), so it's fairly easy to use that query to collect the data, then use code to configure the result set into an array of record to record-data relationship.

I'm working with both MySQL and SQL Server (2005), and have used the PIVOT operator with SQL server, but that kills performance (it's a rather massive DB).

The main concern here is that I can definitely grab each record as a subquery, but eventually (and in the actual production case) pulling larger record sets (maybe 300+ records) with 10-20 data items yields a very large amount of data (3000-6000+ rows).

It seems that the fastest query is just to do the left join, and format the data through the code. Subqueries seem to be second (see the [DB-Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/keyzUfoYsXU9yFzyEEyu7Q/4))

From looking at other similar questions on SO and other places, it seems there are many ways to do this pivot either with a PIVOT operator, with a common table expression, temporary tables, and/or subqueries, but most of those depend on an aggregate in the pivot (i.e. pivot by max(data)), but in this situation, it's just a many-to-one relationship. For any one record, there is only one data entry for each data type.

TLDR: Are there better ways to optimize a query like [this](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/keyzUfoYsXU9yFzyEEyu7Q/4)?

Thanks!

Comment: MySql <> SQL Server

Comment: This is clearly mysql so I removed the sql server tag.

Comment: Yep, the example SQL is definitely MySQL, but I'm curious about SQL Server as well, since I work with both. The PIVOT operator is only on SQL Server, to my knowledge, as well